# Java Login Program

Tags: java, authentication

I wrote a very basic login program in Java recently and I'm doing everything right, but I always get that the username doesn't match.

Here is the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creation
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Create Username:");
        int password = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Create Password:\nOBS! Password Must Be Numbers!"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success! Login Created!\nTransferring you to login screen...");

        //Login
        String loginu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Username:");
        int loginp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Password:"));

        if (username == loginu && password == loginp) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");

        }else if (username == loginu && password != loginp) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password doesn't match.");

        }else if (username != loginu && password == loginp) {
            //always end up here!?
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username doesn't match.");

        }else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong.");

        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: use `equals()` instead of "=="

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.equals`  when comparing strings as they are not primitives but objects. Please see the below code . Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for detailed answer

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class fsdfd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creation
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Create Username:");
        int password = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Create Password:\nOBS! Password Must Be Numbers!"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Success! Login Created!\nTransferring you to login screen...");

        // Login
        String loginu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Username:");
        int loginp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Password:"));

        if (username.equals(loginu) && password == loginp) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");

        } else if (username.equals(loginu) && password != loginp) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password doesn't match.");

        } else if (!username.equals(loginu) && password == loginp) {
            // You wont end up now
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username doesn't match.");

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong.");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well now i end up in "something went wrong"... should i delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Use String equals method for comparison instead of ==.

```
username.equals(loginu) && password.equals(loginp)
```